# Using Two Different Versions of Modernizr on One Website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modernizr

I am trying to use a bootstrap theme ([Worthy](http://htmlcoder.me/worthy-free-bootstrap-template)) as the base for a website. The theme works very well, however I am having problems adding [this scrolling timeline](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/12/05/lateral-on-scroll-sliding-with-jquery/) feature to it.

Here's what I know:

1. I can get the demo of the timeline working
2. I can get the template working
3. I can get the timeline implemented in the template w/ the .css working
4. I CANNOT get the animations of the timeline working in the template

I have traced the issue to one of the timeline's required files, namely a customized version of modernizr. (The template uses the standard version of modernizr). When I remove the the reference to the custom modernizr, the site generally works, but the timeline animations do not. When I add the reference to the custom modernizr back in, all of the site's content disappears.

Does anybody have any suggestions of how I can go about diagnosing and debugging the problem? I know that I have not posted any code, as I'm not sure what is and is not relevant. If somebody can please point me in the right direction, then I can follow up with more targeted questions.

UPDATE: I have also tried removing the template's version of modernizr and only using the one from the timeline, but that also results in all of the site's content disappearing.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How different are these versions of modernizr? Does one contain plugins or tweaks that can be added to the other?

Comment: @ssube - that's a great question. To be honest, I'm not super clear on what modernizr does or how it works, so I don't feel confident intelligently answering your question. HOWEVER, I've run a diff on the files here: http://www.mergely.com/2PWJEOWW/ (left = custom for timeline, right = template). Perhaps you can please continue to help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Modernizr has an [build tool](http://modernizr.com/download) that you can customize to be *exactly* what you need it to be. What you would want to do is get a list of all of the detects that you need, then build a new custom one that contains everything.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Do you know if there's a way to see what Modernizr features were included in these solutions and then I can create my own that has all of the features I need... Thanks!

Comment: from the javascript console, `Object.keys(Modernizr)` should output all of the features being used